# Закрывает программу сразу после открытия С++

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Не могу понять в чем причина. Есть программа на С++. Но как только ее запускаю, сразу же закрывается и выдает ошибку Виндовс. в компиляторе никаких ошибок нет.
Что можно сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int n,m,max,i_max,j_max,i_last_null,j_last_null;
    int A[n][m];
    cout << "строки: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "колоны: ";
    cin >> m;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<m;j++){
            cin>>A[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Введенный массив: ";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
        cout << setw(4) << A[i][j];
      }
    cout<<endl;
    }

    max = A[0][0];
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<m;j++){
        if(A[i][j]>max){
            max = A[i][j];
            i_max = i;
            j_max = j;
        }
        if(A[i][j] == 0){
            i_last_null = i;
            j_last_null = j;
        }
    }
}
cout << "\n";

int temp = A[i_last_null][j_last_null];
A[i_last_null][j_last_null] = A[i_max][j_max];
A[i_max][j_max] = temp;

for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j<m;j++){
        cout << setw(4) << A[i][j];
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
cout << endl;

system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можно запустить ее под отладчиком и посмотреть где же ошибка

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Можете помочь с этим?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я бы остановился уже на этом куске

```
int n,m,
int A[n][m];
cout << "строки: ";
cin >> n;
cout << "колоны: ";
cin >> m;
```

То есть, вначале объявляем массив неведомого размера, а потом вводим его размеры. И потом его используем. Массив сам не поменяется под введенные размеры. Думаю, что просто перетащить строку объявления массива ниже ввода уже будет сильное улучшение (хотя надо ещё и память выделять правильно, студийный компилятор VLA не поддерживает, похоже у Вас mingw). А дальше вроде все правдоподобно.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное.
Действительно, помогло.